# Semantic UI Menu links are not Clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, semantic-ui

Hey I've been working on a project for a with Rails (v4.1.2), Ruby (v2.2.2), and the gem `less-rails-semantic_ui`.

So far I have a layout that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu-bar" class="ui vertical menu">
      <%= link_to 'Dashboard', :dashboard, id: 'dashboard-link', class:(current_page?(:dashboard) ? 'active item' : 'item') %>
      <%= link_to 'Wiki', :wiki, id: 'wiki-link', class: (current_page?(:wiki) ? 'active item' : 'item') %>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    //content here, cut out
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And some basic less:

```
//*= require semantic_ui/semantic_ui

@errorColor: hsl(359, 100%, 50%);
@infoColor: hsl(119, 100%, 62%);

.setWidth(@amount) {
  min-width: @amount;
  max-width: @amount;
  width: @amount;
}

.setHeight(@amount) {
  min-height: @amount;
  max-height: @amount;
  height: @amount;
}

.ui .nag .fatal {
  .title {
    color: darken(@errorColor, 20%);
 }
 background-color: errorColor;
 border-color: lighten(@errorColor, 20%);
}

.ui .nag .error {
  .title {
    color: darken(@errorColor, 10%);
  }
  background-color: errorColor;
  border-color: lighten(@errorColor, 30%);
 }

.ui .nag .info {
  .title {
    color: darken(@infoColor, 20%);
  }
  background-color: infoColor;
  border-color: lighten(@infoColor, 20%);
}

.ui .nag .alert {
   .title {
     color: darken(@infoColor, 10%);
   }
   background-color: infoColor;
   border-color: lighten(@infoColor, 30%);
}

#wrapper {
  .setWidth(100%);
 .setHeight(100%);
}

#menu-bar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -999;
  .setWidth(10%);
  .setHeight(100%);
  float: left;
}

#content {
  .setWidth(89%);
  float: right;

  #flashes {
    .setWidth(100%);
    .setHeight(20%);
  }

  #yielded-content {
    .setWidth(100%);
    .setHeight(79%);
  }
}
```

With Coffeescript that doesn't reference this at all. However the menu links such as dashboard, and wiki are not clickable. I've tried adding the active items to divs surrounding the links. However still the links aren't clickable. Looking at the html using F12 the link are generated right, and show as `<a href='/wiki' class='item'>Wiki</a>` However they aren't clickable at all (appear black, no different cursor position, and nothing happens on clicking).

Comment: If you remove `z-index: -999` from `#menu-bar` in your less file ? Are links visible and clickable ?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks very much.